# I got an error message when I execute the command 'sudo nginx -t '

Tags: 18.04, nginx

I got an error message when I execute the command as root:

```
nginx -t
```

Error:

```
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (13: Permission denied);
```

And There is nothing happend when I execute the command:

```
sudo lsof -i tcp:80
```

OS: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: Does some other copy of `nginx` or some other process already have port 80 open? `sudo lsof -i tcp:80` will show you.

Comment: nginx needs to be run as root in order to bind to port 80.  Use a port above 1000.  (sudo is not root) Try `sudo -i` and then `nginx -t` to run as "root".  If that shows the same message you already have nginx running

Comment: I've did that , but I got the same error message